# How can I calculate $E[\min\{\tau \geq 1| Y_\tau \geq Y_0\}]$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution

> Suppose $X_0, X_1, ... $ is an infinite series of i.i.d. random variables $\sim U([1; n])$. $T = \min\{\tau \geq 1| Y_\tau \geq Y_0\}$. How can I calculate $E[T]$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_0,T)$?

If $X_0 = x$ were fixed, $T$ would have been geometrically distributed with parameter $\frac{n - x}{n - 1}$, and thus $E[T]$ would have been $\frac{n - 1}{n - x}$. But, unfortunately, it isn't.

Comment: Hi, do you know the [Optional sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem)?

Comment: Hi, no we don't learn this theorem. @SamratMukhopadhyay

Comment: What is $n$? (in $Uni(1, n)$ which I assume to be uniform distribution on $[1; n]$)

Comment: @YaniorWeg that's right

Comment: Thank you! But you still didn't tell me, what does the variable $n$ denote... Currently, I see two possible interpretations: first one is that $n$ is some fixed constant (and in that case all $X_k$ are i.i.d.), the second one is that it is the index of $X_n$ (that means each $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on $[1; n]$ for the corresponding $n$). Which of these interpretations is the correct one?

Comment: the value of each Xi varies from 1 to n @YaniorWeg

Comment: What is $T$?  What does "minimal index which is greater than zero" mean?  It seems to me that means $T=1$ if we consider the indices $\{0, 1, 2, ...\}$...? But that has nothing to do with the random variables $\{X_k\}$. And it is still unclear what $Uni(1,n)$ means or "uniform distribution on $[1;n]$ " means (integers?  Real numbers? What does the semicolon mean?)

Answer (score 1):

Let's replace $X_n$ with $Y_n := \frac{X_n - 1}{n - 1}$. Then our problem will be the following one:

> Suppose $Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, ... $ are i.i.d. random variables $\sim U([0; 1])$. $T = \min\{\tau \geq 1| Y_\tau \geq Y_0\}$. Calculate $E[T]$.

$P(Y_n > x| Y_0 = x) = 1 - x$ and $P(Y_n < x| Y_0 = x) = x$. Thus $P(T = k|X_0 = x) = x^{k-1}(1 - x)$. That results in $P(T = k) = \int_0^{1} x^{k-1}(1 - x)dx = \frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$. Thus $E[T] = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty kP(T = k) = \sum_{i = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{k + 1} = \infty$ as [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence). Thus $T$ doesn't have finite first moment.

Comment: You don't need conditional probabilities and integration. By symmetry, the probability that $Y_k$ is the highest and $Y_0$ the second-highest of the first $k+1$ variables is $\frac1{k(k+1)}$.